# Scheduling Batch class

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled

```
  How to schedule the batch for every two hours per day? 
  I try like this 

   String schedule = '0 0 1/2 * * ?';
   System.schedule('Jobname',schedule,new SampleTracking());
```

but i don't know it is corrrect or not.I execute it in developer console it shows the start time as after 2hours from the current time.

Thanks

Venkatsforce

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with the following [cron](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) string.

```
apexScheduledJob myJob = new apexScheduledJob ();
String sch = '0 0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 ? * *';
System.schedule('My Job', sch, myJob);
```

This job will run every 2 hours, at the top of the hour, starting at midnight.

Comment: If i want to run the batch in particular times like 12 AM(midnight),8 AM, 4 PM but i schedule the batch like this                 String schedule = '0 0 0,8,16 * * ?';                 System.schedule('My Job', schedule , new myJob()); Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that should work